# How to store values for each iteration to matrix when using optimizer for registration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, registration

In Matlab, I can use optimizer to get the transform matrix between two images.When I set DisplayOptimization to true, it outputs each iterations and corresponding metric value on the command line. My question is how to store them in a matrix so that I can process those data later?

```
tformSimilarity = imregtform(moving,fixed,'similarity',optimizer,metric,'DisplayOptimization',true);
```

Command Window Output:

```
Maximizing Mutual Information...

Pyramid Level: 1

Iteration    Mattes Mutual Information
1            0.3784        
2            0.4435        
3            0.4436        
4            0.4436        
5            0.4467        
6            0.4467        
7            0.4748        
8            0.4748        
9            0.4803        
10           0.4803        
11           0.4803        
12           0.4803        
13           0.4803        
14           0.4803        
15           0.4803        
16           0.4803        
17           0.4803        
18           0.4803        
19           0.4803        
20           0.4803        
21           0.4803        
22           0.4803        
23           0.4803        
24           0.4883        
25           0.4883        
26           0.4909        
27           0.4915        
28           0.4915        
29           0.4915        
30           0.4915        
31           0.4915        
32           0.4956        
33           0.4956        
34           0.4956        
35           0.4956        
36           0.4956        
37           0.4956        
38           0.4956        
39           0.4956        
40           0.4956        
41           0.4987        
42           0.4987        
43           0.5178        
44           0.5178        
45           0.5459        
46           0.5459        
47           0.5459        
48           0.5459        
49           0.5459        
50           0.5459        
51           0.5459        
52           0.5459        
53           0.5459        
54           0.5459        
55           0.5459        
56           0.5459        
57           0.5459        
58           0.5503        
59           0.5503        
60           0.5503        
61           0.5503        
62           0.5503        
63           0.5503        
64           0.5563        
65           0.5563        
66           0.5563        
67           0.5563        
68           0.5563        
69           0.5571        
70           0.5843        
71           0.5843        
72           0.6132        
73           0.6947        
74           0.7119        
75           0.7119        
76           0.7119        
77           0.7119        
78           0.7119        
79           0.7119        
80           0.7463        
81           0.7463        
82           0.7463        
83           0.7463        
84           0.7463        
85           0.7463   
...
```

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is to use [`diary`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! Can diary store them into a matrix? I only need numbers. Can you give me a quick example?

Comment: You can use `diary on` or `diary filename` right before the desired output is produced, and `diary off` afterwards. That creates a file with the command-window text as is. From that you have to trim or parse manually to turn it into a matrix

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. It works. However, using diary is not working if I want to plot the real-time curves based on the metric value.